# Using two strings in the bundle identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update the bundle identifier.

However, I had been told to use only two string rather than three(commonly used) such as, I am just wondering if that would bring any issues or problem?

proposed to use "**com.mobilo**" rather than "**com.mobilo.mobile**"

Comment: You're assuming that the organization associated with `"com.mobilo"` will only have one app. Only you could know if that's appropriate or not, but personally, I wouldn't roll those dice

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, if I want to create other app called `crazy`, let's call `com.mobile.crazy`, then this bundle identifier wont will be available then, right?

Comment: I think it could work, but I foresee some issues. If your main app (`"com.mobilo"`) has a watch app counterpart, extensions, widgets etc. the bundle identifiers of those would be nested under `com.mobilo`, like `com.mobilo.watch-app`, `com.mobilo.widget`, etc. In that context `com.mobilo.crazy` looks like an extension or widget, rather than a full fledged app